# Slow refresh in Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, random

I have a site that through a piece of javascript and php code takes a folder, randomly picks an image and then shows it in a div tag on the page. Whilst all this works properly, showing the image in the right size and all. There is still a minor issue, it is pretty slow. Upon clicking the refresh button, it instantly shows an image, though if pressed again it won't instantly show a new image unless pressed after 10 or so seconds. Whilst this of course, is a minor issue, it is pretty annoying. I've tried a few things such as using html meta tags to clear the cache/not store it in order to always refresh, but it didn't work. I've also tried numerous of different javascript code that I found on stackoverflow.com of other ways to do it, but they all seemed to only refresh if pressed after 10 or so seconds.

Considering there's quite a lot of code. I've put the code into a pastebin for simplicity.

Note that the PHP code is borrowed from the WWW, and I have done very minor changes to it, less than none except adding the last line of code.

http://pastebin.com/wwys5r3E

Hope we can find a solution together, thanks!

Comment: how many images do you have in said folder

Comment: Quite a lot to be frank, 100 to be exact. Is that possibly a problem? EDIT: Although I do have other folders that have only ~40 images, and it also only allows a refresh every 10th second for those too.

Comment: how many other files ? not just images ?

Comment: In the same folder as the images? none, in total? On the web server I have approximately 1336 files including images and everything.

Comment: There seems to be code missing in your pastebin, please include the missing pieces

Comment: Yeah I excluded some of the code, what would you like to see? The rest I don't reckon the last bit has anything to do but here's the rest from the php file: http://pastebin.com/21RJd8gP The other .php files look exactly alike yet put to a different folder of a different name

Comment: I don't see anything that would be causing the slow down other then reading the files in the directory but honestly only 100 images it should be a split second.

Comment: I agree, if you would like to try it out on your own here's the link: http://send2me.dk/steffen/random-hero.php as stated the site itself is pretty simple (yet I still need to fix that it's not particularly symmetric, but that comes later) just click the refresh button and see for yourself that if you click it right after, it doesn't update instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the requests are defiantly getting cached server side.

```
function reloadImg(){

            if(document.refreshform.randomhero[1].checked == true) {
                    $("#randomhero").load("random-herosup.php?u="+new Date().getTime());
            }
            else if(document.refreshform.randomhero[2].checked == true) {
                    $("#randomhero").load("random-herocar.php?u="+new Date().getTime());
            }
            else if(document.refreshform.randomhero[3].checked == true) {
                    $("#randomhero").load("random-heromid.php?u="+new Date().getTime());
            }
            else
            {
                    $("#randomhero").load("random-heroall.php?u="+new Date().getTime());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad we got through it together, again thank you so very much! (As I don't quite have enough reputation, I can't vote you up, but consider an invisible up vote from here! :) )